# JAVA Sort lines in ascending order in new file and display it

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, printwriter

I'm writing a simple game guessing in java using eclipse. Now I want to print out the details in ascending order. I tried many ways that I found on this forum,but couldn't solve it. That's why I need your help.

My code are as follows :

```
File f = new File ("scores.txt");
    // name of the folder created at the root of the project
    String ligne;
    try
    {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (f, true)));
    if (numberOfTries==1){
        pw.println (numberOfTries + " try by " + str )  ; 
    }
    else if (numberOfTries!=1){
        pw.println (numberOfTries + " tries by " + str )    ; 
    }

//  pw.println (numberOfTries)  ;
    pw.close ();    
    // this line MUST be written.
    }

    catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println ("Error while writing data:" + exception.getMessage());
    }       

    BufferedReader ficTexte;
    // to read from a folder text.
try {
        ficTexte = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(f));
        do {
            ligne= ficTexte.readLine();
            if (ligne !=null)
            // if the line is not empty.
               System.out.println(ligne);
        } while (ligne !=null);
        ficTexte.close();
        System.out.println("\n");
        }
    // Show message in case of errors.
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

Suppose I have

```
3 tries by Vibe
2 tries by NoNo
10 tries by Caroline
7 tries by Mata
10 tries by Lionel
```

and I want it to be arranged as follows :

```
2 tries by NoNo
3 tries by Vibe
7 tries by Mata
10 tries by Caroline
10 tries by Lionel
```

How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static final Comparator<String> CMP = new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final String a, final String b)
    {
        final int inta = Integer.parseInt(a.split("\\s+")[0]);
        final int intb = Integer.parseInt(b.split("\\s+")[0]);
        return Integer.compare(inta, intb);
    }
}
```

Then, later in code:

```
final Path file = Paths.get("scores.txt");
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Collections.sort(lines, CMP);

for (final String line: lines)
    System.out.println(line);
```

(similarly you should use `Files.newBufferedWriter()` to get a `Writer` to your file)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but where should I put the private code? I try insert in the same java file, it give syntax error. Should I create a new java file and execute the java file with the private function?

Comment: No, just declare it at the beginning of your class (talking about `CMP` I guess)

Comment: I enter my full code here 
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/2eOQOY" type="text/javascript" ></script>
in the code, i already insert the "final Path ..." 
please help with the error.

Comment: This is not the code I provided -- for one, what did you do to `CMP`? It was _meant_ to be a `Comparator<String>` and initialized as I wrote

Comment: It's because when I insert the code, it give an error (CMP cannot be resolved to a variable) and recommand to add a static variable , so I just go on with it. what should I do? 
I edited the code and removed the private static, it doesnt function now. error at the CMP.

Comment: Your code is seriously broken then. `CMP` should be defined in the class it is used as a private static final class field

Comment: I posted the original code before I added the CMP and final path code. 
here : <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/8rVmOh" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
i have idea but don't know the code, i'm new to java.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution:

1. Write code to read all rows in the file and store them in a List of your choosing (ArrayList seems reasonable).  Check out [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
2. Write a custom comparator to perform your sort.  Check out [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  As in the fge answer, compare two strings.  Unlike in that answer, don't use matcher, which feels like overkill to me.  Instead just call String.split() and refer to the first element in the returned array (index zero).  Convert this to a number perform the comparison.
3. Collections.sort(rows, yourComparator) (just like in the fge answer).
4. Write the rows to a file of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I have been trying and still can get it right. got error, but not sure where.